# Fetching a row if the select query count is only one

Tags: sql, oracle

We were trying to retrieve the values if the select query only returns one row. Below is the tried solution but wanted to check if there is optimized solution with case logic.

Tried query:

```
select * from employees
WHERE  department_id = 204
AND class_id = 162
AND (select count(1)
    from employees
    WHERE department_id = 204
    and class_id = 162
    HAVING count(employee_id) = 1) = 1
```

Comment: Should there be an `AND` after the first occurrence of `class_id = 162` in this query? Otherwise it's not a valid statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the analytical function as follows:

```
select * from
(select t.*, count(1) over () as cnt from employees t
WHERE  department_id = 204
and class_id = 162)
where cnt = 1
```

Comment: Thanks Tejash, this worked but what does over() do ?

Comment: That is the syntax of window(analytical) function. You must learn this powerful fetaure of oracle.

Answer (score 1):

Use a window function:

```
select e.*
from (select e.*, count(*) as cnt
      from employees e
      where department_id = 204 and class_id = 162
     ) e
where cnt = 1;
```

Comment: This was the one I was trying but getting the exception ORA-00937: not a single-group group function.